# Understanding change of basis and subspaces (problem)

Tags: vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Can you please help me to understand this?

I was given 2 basis (P₂[R] space)

B₁ = {x^2+ x + 1, x, x-1}

B₂ = {x^2 - x + 1, x, 2}

If S ∈ P₂ is a "proper" - "own" subspace (my teacher said that it means the subspace is included but its not the same) and L₁ and L₂ basis of S.

How can i know if the change of matrix from L₁ to B₂ exist? from L₁ to L₂? What would be the size of the matrix?

Can you please help me to understand this? I dont get it :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have one basis $\{b_1, b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ and you want to convert it into another basis $\{c_1, c_2, c_3,\ldots,c_m\}$, all you have to do is find out how to express each new basis vector in terms of the old basis vectors:

> Find the missing coefficients ($\square$).
>   $$c_1 = \square b_1 + \square b_2 + \square b_3 + \ldots + \square b_n$$
>   $$c_2 = \square b_1 + \square b_2 + \square b_3 + \ldots + \square b_n$$
>   $$\vdots$$
>   $$c_m = \square b_1 + \square b_2 + \square b_3 + \ldots + \square b_n$$

Those coefficients will be the entries in a change-of-basis matrix. The matrix will be $m\times n$ if you have $n$ old vectors and $m$ new vectors.

---

We can apply this technique to your problem:

$$B_1 = \{x^2 + x +1,\, x,\, x-1\} \qquad B_2 = \{x^2 - x + 1,\, x,\, 2\}$$

We need to express every vector in $B_2$ as a weighted sum of vectors in $B_1$. Notice that:

$$\begin{align*}
\color{maroon}{x^2-x+1} &= 1\cdot [\color{teal}{x^2+x+1}]&-2\cdot[\color{teal}{x}] &+0\cdot[\color{teal}{x-1}] \\
\color{maroon}{x} &= 0\cdot [\color{teal}{x^2+x+1}]&+1\cdot[\color{teal}{x}] &+0\cdot[\color{teal}{x-1}] \\
\color{maroon}{2} &= 0\cdot [\color{teal}{x^2+x+1}]&+2\cdot[\color{teal}{x}] &-2\cdot[\color{teal}{x-1}] \\
\end{align*}$$

And so our change of basis matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 0\\0&1&0\\0&2&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

It transforms any vector written as $a(\color{maroon}{x^2-x+1}) + b(\color{maroon}{x}) + c(\color{maroon}{2})$ into the corresponding vector $a^\prime(\color{teal}{x^2+x+1}) + b^\prime(\color{teal}{x}) + c^\prime(\color{teal}{x-1})$.

---

Now the last question. If $S$ is a proper subspace of $P_2$, you will need to know that its basis will have fewer vectors than $P_2$. Because $P_2$ has three basis vectors, a proper subspace $S$ will have one or two basis vectors.

We don't know what those basis vectors in $L$ will be. However, we know that they will be vectors in $P_2$. We have a basis for $P_2$; therefore, we can write the basis vectors in $L$ as a linear combination of basis vectors in $P_2$. When we write the basis vectors in $L$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors for the main space $P_2$, the matrix of coefficients gives the transformation into that subspace.

Comment: Dude, you are AWESOME!!
Can i ask you something?What would have happened if i have been given this: "If S ∈ P₂ is a "trivial" subspace"?Whats the difference between "proper"/"own" subspace AND trivial?Is it the same for polynomials, vector, matrices?

Comment: Glad to help! A trivial subspace of $V$ is either the zero subspace or the entire space $V$ itself.  So every subspace is either trivial or proper. Vectors are, essentially, anything you can add together and multiply by constants. Polynomials are an example of vectors for this reason. Vector space definitions (such as "trivial subspace") are the same no matter which vector space you're talking about, which is why vectors are such a useful abstraction. Matrices transform one set of vectors into another through weighted sums.

Comment: Thank you for replying!!
Example:Suppose that i have 2 basis (R^4 space)
B₁={2,5,4,3)
B₂ =(3, 12,9,7)
If S ∈ R4 is a "proper" - "own" subspace and L₁ and L₂ basis of S.
What would be the size of the matrix?

Comment: A correction: If $\mathbb{R}^4$ means Euclidean space, your basis needs to consist of four linearly-independent *vectors* (each one is a vector like $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$), whereas you have the basis being four numbers.   Besides this, the size of the matrix depends on how many basis vectors are in $L$. Can you figure out what the rule is for the size of the matrix by looking at the "find the missing coefficients" part of the answer above?

Comment: Duude, i think theres something wrong with your change of basis matrix from B₂ to B₁.. I got this matrix:
[1...0...0]
[-2..1...2]
[0...0..-2]

Comment: I tried but i could not get the basis for L :/

Comment: @JustToKnow, My matrix turns $B_1 \rightarrow B_2$. I think your matrix turns $B_2 \rightarrow B_1$. They're the same except the rows of my matrix are the columns of your matrix.

Comment: Yeah, im sorry dude!!.
I do not know how to get the basis for L.. i am a little dizzy, i dont understand pal :(.. I´ve tried without success.. i mean, take a look:
I think i could write the basis vectors in L as a linear combination of basis vectors in P2 but i do not know how to do that :(

ax2+bx+c=α(x2+x+1)+β(x)+δ(x−1)
ax2+bx+c=α(x2−x+1)+β(x)+δ(2)

Comment: Well, $S$ is a proper subspace of three-dimensional $P_2$. Hence a basis $L$ of $S$ has one or two basis vectors. We're dealing with vectors in $P_2$, so the basis vectors look like $L=\{ax^2+bx+c, dx^2+ex+f\}$ where $a,\ldots, f$ are constants. If this is all we know about $L$, we can compute a change of basis matrix in terms of $a,\ldots, f$.

Comment: I dont understand what you did.. how did you get to this: L={ax2+bx+c,dx2+ex+f}

Comment: A basis for a space $S$ is a set of things in $S$. Because $P_2$ is the set of all quadratic polynomials $ax^2 + bx + c$, and because $S$ is a subset of $P_2$, a basis of $S$ is a set of quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Dude, you said "we know that they will be vectors in P2. We have a basis for P2; therefore, we can write the basis vectors in L as a linear combination of basis vectors in P2. When we write the basis vectors in L as a linear combination of the basis vectors for the main space P2, the matrix of coefficients gives the transformation into that subspace." Where did you do the linear combination?

Comment: Can you please help me to understand that.. i dont get it.. i thought you were going to do a linear combination using the basis of P2.. something like this: ax2+bx+c=α(x2+x+1)+β(x)+δ(x−1) and
ax2+bx+c=α(x2−x+1)+β(x)+δ(2)

Comment: You're exactly right. All I did was name the basis vectors $ax^2 + bx + c$ and $dx^2 + ex + f$. The next step is to write them as a linear combination the way you suggest.  When we do, we get $$ax^2 + bx +c = a(x^2+x+1) + (-2a + b + c)x + (a-c)(x-1)$$ The way I got that answer was by figuring out what the coefficient on $(x^2+x+1)$ must be, given that it's the only term containing $x^2$. Then I figured the $(x-1)$ term, since only it contains a constant 1. Finally, the $x$ coefficient is chosen.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Okay, so.. what would be the basis for L.

Comment: Wouldnt it be L=(L₁,L₂), L₁,L₂ basis.......
L₁--ax2+bx+c=α(x2+x+1)+β(x)+δ(x−1) and
L₂--ax2+bx+c=α(x2−x+1)+β(x)+δ(2)
How do you get the basis from both linear combinations?

Comment: I wanted to show you how to do it without doing the whole problem. $$L_1 = ax^2 + bx +c = a(x^2+x+1) + (-2a + b + c)x + (a-c)(x-1)$$  $$L_2 = dx^2 + ex + f = d(x^2+x+1) + (-2d + e + f)x + (d-f)(x-1)$$

Comment: You are helping me a lot, dude :)
I do not understand.. from here:
L1=ax2+bx+c=a(x2+x+1)+(−2a+b+c)x+(a−c)(x−1)..
L2=dx2+ex+f=d(x2+x+1)+(−2d+e+f)x+(d−f)(x−1)..
What are the basis?

Comment: What is your definition of a basis?

Comment: A set that span the space and its linearly independent :/

Comment: I do not understand dude.. it says: "Is it possible to build a change of coordinates matrix from L₁ to B₂.. and from L₁ to L₂?What would be their size?" I do not understand :(

Comment: Maybe it would help to solve some problems in other spaces: what if you had a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, like $$B_1 = \{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$$ and two bases for the same proper subspace: $$L_1 = \{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$$ and $$L_2=\{\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\}$$ What transformations are possible? What size will the matrix be? Hint: how many equations and how many variables?

Comment: But, can you explain me this?
You got this (and me too):
L1=ax2+bx+c=a(x2+x+1)+(−2a+b+c)x+(a−c)(x−1)..
L2=dx2+ex+f=d(x2+x+1)+(−2d+e+f)x+(d−f)(x−1)
You wrote this: "When we write the basis vectors in L as a linear combination of the basis vectors for the main space P2, the matrix of coefficients gives the transformation into that subspace.". How can i get the the matrix of coefficients with the given information?

Comment: [read the previos message]I think im not clear.. im sorry. I mean, i got this:
L1=ax2+bx+c=a(x2+x+1)+(−2a+b+c)x+(a−c)(x−1).. L2=dx2+ex+f=d(x2+x+1)+(−2d+e+f)x+(d−f)(x−1)
How can i build the change of basis matrix from L1 to L2.. i do not understand how to make it with these "strange" L1 and L2 bases?

Comment: Oh I think I was using confusingly inconsistent notation, sorry. What we have is $L_1 = \{ax^2+bx+c, dx^2 + ex + f\}$ and $L_2 = \{gx^2+hx+i, jx^2 + kx + \ell\}$. You can transform $B_1\rightarrow L_1$ using the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-2a+b+c&a-c\\d&-2d+e+f&d-f\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73020/discussion-between-justtoknow-and-user326210).

Comment: Im sorry, i feel a little "stupid" but can you please write the final change of matrix basis from L1 to L2 and L1 to B2?

Comment: Dude, then.. Is it possible to build a change of coordinates matrix from L₁ to B₂.. and from L₁ to L₂?What would be their size?